# How to shift the red border underneath of black box?

Tags: css

I am trying to shift the red border underneath of the black box. How shall I shift the red border?

This is for a css project. In the past I tried to shift the div in html, but the result is unchanged.

```css
#box{
width:150px;
padding:5px;
height:30px;
background-color:#323232;
float:right;
color:white;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

#border{
border-bottom:2px solid red;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Text Goes Inside</div>


<div id="border"></div>
```

Here how it should look like

[image]

Comment: if you float your button, then you have to clear your border. Give #border a `clear:both`

Answer (score 1):

Simple: instead of using float to get your box to the right, use `margin-left: auto;`

So you can change your CSS to:

```
#box {
    width:150px;
    padding:5px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#323232;
    margin-left: auto;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#border {
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g602ex5c/).

Answer (score 0):

`Float: right;` is what is making the border go above your box. If you add `clear: both;` to your border it should display how you'd like.

```css
#box{
width:150px;
padding:5px;
height:30px;
background-color:#323232;
float:right;
color:white;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

#border{
border-bottom:2px solid red;
position: relative;
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Text Goes Inside</div>


<div id="border"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

html:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner" id="box">Text Goes Inside</div>
<div class="inner" id="border"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box{
width:150px;
padding:5px;
height:30px;
background-color:#323232;
color:white;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
position: relative;
}

#border{
border-bottom:2px solid red;
position: relative;
}

.outer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Instead of just pasting code to fix the OP's problem, please add a description to your answer explaining what was wrong with OP's problem, and how to solve it. Pasting a code solution is unhelpful without context.